Configuring LSP to recognize TailwindCSS @apply directives in Vue scoped SCSS with LazyVim
I'm using LazyVim in a Vue project. In <style lang="scss" scoped> blocks, I keep getting an "Unknown at rule @apply" error for TailwindCSS @apply directives.
LSP configs active in this buffer (I found this via the Lspinfo command):
(vtsls, tailwindcss, volar)
I've tried setting css.lint.unknownAtRules = "ignore" but still seeing the issue. Is there a way to configure an LSP to recognize @apply in these scoped SCSS blocks?

Any help would be appreciated!

This is not an error but a warning. Give a try to this one: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/5258#discussioncomment-1979394

Might be as simple as "scss.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore".

Hi @kissu, I guess you propose creating a new .lua file in the plugins directory containing this snippet:
return {
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
    opts = {
      servers = {
        cssls = {
          settings = {
            scss = {
              lint = {
                unknownAtRules = "ignore",
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }

Unfortunately, this is not solving the issue.

Not a neovim expert, but GPT doesn't give that one. Try to look around a bit more to find out where to put it. Or give a try to this one: https://www.reddit.com/r/lunarvim/comments/w50jfk/need_help_with_fixing_unknown_at_rules_in_css/

I followed the Reddit advice exactly, but it's still not working. Am I missing something? And if it's a bug, where should I report it? Thanks!

I found the solution! Turns out I actually needed to update the volar LSP instead of cssls.
return {
  {
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
    opts = {
      servers = {
        volar = {
          settings = {
            css = {
              validate = true,
              lint = {
                unknownAtRules = "ignore",
              },
            },
            scss = {
              validate = true,
              lint = {
                unknownAtRules = "ignore",
              },
            },
            less = {
              validate = true,
              lint = {
                unknownAtRules = "ignore",
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}


Yes, this is what's written here: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/5258#discussioncomment-9848843 Feel free to accept your own answer when you can.

Try importing utilities in top of style block
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";


Got a link/documentation for this part? Some explanation with an answer is always welcome.
